# Is it possible to render events as dots in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I wanted to render events as dots instead of rectangular bar which the full calendar provides. I tried the `eventContent` prop however, it is not working perfectly fine with the overlapping events.

If an event is a multi day event, it just shows the event dot on the day the evnet has started.

Comment: `it just shows the event dot on the day the evnet has started`...and your expectation would be...? You want it to show a dot on every day that the event occurs? Also, are you just talking about the month view, or also any others?